# Decompile .class file bytecode version 49.0(java 5)

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Не могу посмотреть реализацию метода.

Проваливаюсь в метод у себя в коде, перехожу в метод в классе уже в зависимости.

Идея высвечивает сверху "Decompile .class file bytecode version 49.0(java 5)",

скорее всего это из за того что Идея почему то пишет что это java 5. У меня стоит jdk 8.

кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Что именно Вы не можете посмотреть?

Comment: тело метода по которому перехожу в класс из зависимости

Comment: Так какой метод?

Comment: какая разница. я изучаю код который использует порядка 20 методов  из данной зависимости. signature-util-5.2.4.jar если это важно. и во всех методах не могу посмотреть как они реализованы.

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю проблему, вставьте скрин что-ли.

Comment: "скорее всего это из за того что Идея почему то пишет что это java 5" - не из-за этого точно

Comment: дополните вопрос - приложите скрин того, что происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение "*Decompile .class file bytecode version 49.0(java 5)*" означает, что тот class файл (внутри `signature-util-5.2.4.jar`), который IntelliJ IDEA декомпилирует, был создан компилятором Java 5. Какой у вас JDK совершенно неважно. Если декомпиляция не проходит и вместо Java кода вы продолжаете видеть байткод, то скорее всего ваш класс обработан обфускатором, который предназначен как раз таки для предотвращения или усложнения декомпиляции.

Comment: не уверен что обфускатор может повлиять на декомпиляцию, насколько мне известно он в состоянии только изменить название классов, переменных, полей